# jQuery mobile Column toggle not working for colspan/rowspans

Tags: jquery-mobile, toggle

Jquery mobile column toggle: does NOT work with colspan and rowspan.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Andree643/1nwwcsyu/

Any solutions? How to override the handler to hide/show columns?

Example:

```
A    B    C           D       E
                 D1 D2 D3  E1 E2 E3
--------------------------------------
```

D has sub header D1,D2,D3, and E has sub header E1,E2,E3

When hiding column D, its sub headers should be hidden. But instead, E1 is hidden when hidding column D.  Obviously, rowspan is ignored.

```
A    B    C           D                  E
                 ---------------       ----------
                  D1    D2     D3      E1  E2  E3
              ------- ------- -------
               F    G  H   I   J   K
```

It does not working for tree-structred column headers.

Comment: For me your fiddle seems to work. What results exactly are you expecting?

Comment: added an example with sub headers. Thanks.

Comment: If a class is added to a header and its descendant sub headers, is there a way to hide a sub tree?

Comment: If you are hardcoding your table, you could use classes like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/1nwwcsyu/2/   (detect column toggle by listening for change on the popup checkboxes)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. It would be nice without adding the hidden headers A/B/C on the second row, and instead use rowspan to figure out which sub headers to hide.